# Please tell me which trainer aircraft is this?

Tags: aircraft-identification, pakistan

This trainer aircraft was spotted by me on a video on youtube, which said they were at the Lahore Flying Club. I really could not tell what aircraft they were on. If anyone can tell me, that would be great. Its some Cessna but which?

link to the youtube video:

Picture from the video attached.[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its a [Zenair Zodiac CH601 XL](http://www.zenithair.com/zodiac/xl/index.html) you can see the registration code on the side and if you watch the video a bit more they show the inside of the cockpit and you see the registration code a bit more clearly, which [you can look up here](https://houser747.files.wordpress.com/2011/05/ap-current-17-may-2011.pdf). It appears to be [owned by this flying club.](http://usfc.com.pk/assembly.html)